# Using swagger with Blazor WebAssembly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, swagger, blazor, swashbuckle

I have been playing with blazor wasm and hit a problem with using swagger on the server project that is created by the default project.  This problem only happens in Chrome, and not Edge.

The problem is very odd, I have set up swagger and when I go to https://localhost:44323/swagger/index.html I get a working swagger page, but when I try to use any of my controllers or even the default weather one it just runs and sits there saying loading forever.  If I put break point in the controller it does get hit.
If I open the browser debug tools, and stop it it will say "Paused in the debuger" the browser will flicker and then it will show results.

If i go to https://localhost:44323/WeatherForecast it runs and give the correct response.

I added the project in Visual studio, going new project => selecting blazor app => Blazor WebAssembly App, and selecting AspNetCore hosted, and Progressive Web Application.

I have installed via nuget
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen v5.5.0

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI v5.5.0

My entire start up class is

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        //Added Swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen(setUpAction =>
        {
            setUpAction.SwaggerDoc("PetStoreAPI", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "PetStore API", Version = "1" });

            //Add comments, to get this to work you need to go into project properties, build tab, then select "XML Documentation file"
            var xmlCommentFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlCommentFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentFile);
            setUpAction.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentFullPath);
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
        // This is called AFTER ConfigureServices so things you
        // register here OVERRIDE things registered in ConfigureServices.
        //
        // You must have the call to `UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())`
        // when building the host or this won't be called.

        builder.RegisterModule(new Autofac.AutofacConfiguration());
        builder.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        //Added Swagger
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/PetStoreAPI/swagger.json", "PetStore API");
        });

        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar issue, however I was able to bring it up by adding `services.AddControllers();` right after `services.AddControllersWithViews();`  and `services.AddRazorPages();`.